# opening a website with an ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a responsive website, and I want to make it an app so I can use push notifications with it, right now I can use the `inappbrowser` plugin to open the website I need with this code:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.examplewebsite.com', '_self', 'location=no'); 
    return false;">                
    Open a Browser</a>
```

However this requires for me to click on the link "open a browser", I would like the app to initialize directly on the website I desire.

any ideas if that is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suggest instead using `in-app-browser`, import your website in the ionic and build it in the default web-view ionic provides.

As far as the answer to your question is concerned, you can use it in your ionic app `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback, in your `www/js/app.js`

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$location,$rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    //your in-app-plugin code here
    window.open('http://www.examplewebsite.com', '_self', 'location=no');
    return false;
  });
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you have to just add in-app-browser plugin after that in app.js file post  window.open('http://www.examplewebsite.com', '_self', 'location=no'); nothing else.Yop have't need to add any dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work! on the index file I simply added the onload event:

http://www.mywebsite.com', '_self', 'location=no'); return false;">

Thanks a lot!